# Rails google places api address autocomplete. Pass address values into @model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I need to pass the address values such as address, city, postal code , etc. To my @model where I have fields to accomodate the values.

I have been struggling trying many different things, including some ajax that looked like chinese..... , the last 3 days. I need help. If you have the time, there seems to be many people struggling with the same. Id love if someone could provide a complete solution/tutorial.

Auto-completes works fine, populating the google fields with the different element values. I thought I could use erb hidden_fields and assign the html values to my erb form fields but I cant get it to work.

Inside my regular erb form i have the Google Places API web form:

```
Start Address auto-complete 
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<style>
  #locationField, #controls {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
  }
  #autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 99%;
  }
  .label {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    color: #303030;
  }
  #address {
    border: 1px solid #000090;
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
    width: 480px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  #address td {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .field {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .slimField {
    width: 80px;
  }
  .wideField {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #locationField {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
</style>


<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Calle</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
          disabled="true"></input>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Ciudad</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Provincia</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_2"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="label">subloc</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="sublocality"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="label">geocode</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="geocode"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="label">neighborhood</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="neighborhood"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">street address</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="street_address"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="label"></td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="label">Codigo Postal</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Pais</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
          id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>


 <!-- 
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_KEY]&libraries=places"></script>
-->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>



<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>


<!-- End Address auto-complete -->
```

Comment: are you getting the values from the address_components and do you have the correct id fields?

Comment: I get the values from google, My fields are named differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the correct data in the address_attributes, here is a simple example of doing this.

```
$(function () { 
    $("#address").geocomplete({
      details: ".geo-details",
      detailsAttribute: "geo"
    });
});

$(function () { 
    $("#address")
        .geocomplete()
        .bind("geocode:result", function (event, result) {                      
            b = result
            a = result.address_components
            for ( var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                if (a[i].types.indexOf("country") > -1)
                {
                    $('#address_line').val(a[i].long_name)
                }
                if (a[i].types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
                {
                    $('#zipcode').val(a[i].long_name)
                }
                if (a[i].types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') > -1)
                {
                    $('#state').val(a[i].long_name)
                }

            }
                $("#latitude").val(result.geometry.location.lat());
                $("#longitude").val(result.geometry.location.lng());
    });
});
```

Then the form should contain the,
`address_line,  zipcode,  state,  latitude, and longitude` id elements

Comment: You say the form should contain the id elements, you mean that these are my :fields or I should point my :fields to these id's?

Comment: point your fields to these id's and you will get the values filled into the fields through the id's

Comment: To point to the id, If I use <%= f.text_field :myaddresslinefield, id:"address_line" %> I get no errors, but the value is not saved. If I use <%= f.text_field :myaddresslinefield, id="address_line" %> I get error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for "address_line":String): Should I be pointing to the id differentely? tks

Comment: the above example is just the process I have given you shld check whats coming from the result

Comment: is this  `$("#address").geocomplete({
      details: ".geo-details",
      detailsAttribute: "geo"
    });` working for you?

Comment: Not sure whats not worrking, i pasted your code into mine. Could you clarify the right way to point to an id? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117931/discussion-between-sravan-and-francisco).

Answer (score 0):

I finally Solved it using [simple_form Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Here is my code. I collect the whole address in one field(separates by commas), and i then collect all the different elements separately also. Because of my layout I have used hidden erb inputs but they will populate live if you remove the ', :as => :hidden' part.

Hope this helps some of you, its been a tough one for me to figure it out! Enjoy!!

```
<%= simple_form_for(@mymodel) do |f| %>

<!-- The order of erb inputs before html inputs seems to be important! had problems changing it and couldnt remove html inputs either.  -->

<%= f.input :my_model_address, :label => "Direccion", :input_html =>{:id => 'autocomplete'}, :placeholder => 'Empieza con el nombre de la calle...' %>
<%= f.input :my_model_street, :as => :hidden, :as => :hidden, :input_html =>{:id => 'route'} %>
<%= f.input :my_model_street_number, :as => :hidden, :input_html =>{:id => 'street_number'} %>
<%= f.input :my_model_postal_code, :as => :hidden, :input_html =>{:id => 'postal_code'} %>
<%= f.input :my_model_city, :as => :hidden, :input_html =>{:id => 'locality'} %>
<%= f.input :my_model_state, :as => :hidden, :input_html =>{:id => 'administrative_area_level_2'} %>
<%= f.input :my_model_country, :as => :hidden, :input_html =>{:id => 'country'} %>

<input type="hidden" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="route" disabled="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="street_address" disabled="true"></input></td>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"></input></td>
<input type="hidden" class="field" id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>

<!-- End Address auto-complete -->
```